# Python : how to fix this error with _ub in scipy. optimize syntax error

Tags: python, scipy

[image]

I don't know how to deal with this

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `linprog` should use `(...)` instead of `[...]`. Specifically, change to:

```
my_result = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=[x1_bounds,x2_bounds,x3_bounds,x4_bounds])
```